# Mongo average aggregation query with no group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to get the average of a whole field using the aggregation framework in Mongo. However i can't seem to find any example that uses it without a group parameter.

I have the following document structure:

```js
 {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5352703b61d2739b2ea44e4d"),
      "Semana" : "2014-02-23 - 2014-03-01",
      "bolsaDeValores" : "7",
      "bvc" : "8",
      "dollar" : "76",
      "ecopetrol" : "51",
      "dollarPrice" : "18"
 }
```

Basically what i want to do is get the average value of the bvc field, and any other numeric one, for the whole collection in the fastest possible way (without using MapReduce as it is less efficient than the Aggregation Framework).

I have tried to group on a greater than zero basis as well but to no avail:

```js
db.EvaluatedSentiments.aggregate([
    { "$group": { 
        "bvc" : {"$gt:0"}
        }, 
        {
            "bvc" : { "$avg" : "$bvc"}
        }
    }
])
```

I appreciate any help you could provide.

References: [Mongo aggregation manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/MongoDB-aggregation-guide.pdf)

Comment: Group by null instead

Comment: You do actually realize that none of the values you present are actually numeric, don't you? They are in fact all strings.

Comment: That is very true, i hadn't realized about it, an omission i made while storing the vales. Thanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

First of all store numerical values as numbers. Afterwards you can use a simple statement to calculate the average:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ 
  "$group": {
    "_id": null, 
    "avg_bvc": { "$avg": "$bvc" } 
  } 
}])
```

You can simply use more `$avg` aggregation operators to get averages for your other numeric fields:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ 
  "$group": {
    "_id": null, 
    "avg_bvc": { "$avg": "$bvc" }, 
    "avg_dollar": { "$avg": "$dollar" } 
  } 
}])
```

Comment: almost missed the "_id": null. this will group it all in one! genius !

Comment: I had to put brackets [ ] around query to make it work.
`db.collection.aggregate([{ 
  "$group": {
    "_id": null, 
    "avg_bvc": { "$avg": "$bvc" } 
  } 
}])`

Answer (score 7):

So if your data actually was numeric which is it not and your intention is to exclude the documents that have a "greater than zero" value then you include a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) statement in your aggregation pipeline in order to "filter" out these documents:

```js
db.EvaluatedSentiments.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "bvc": { "$gt": 0 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "bvc": { "$avg": "$bvc" }
    }}
])
```

Comment: I want 0 value to display in list but in avg i need to exclude zero.. In this situation the above didnt work.. is there any possiiblities to get it

Answer (score -1):

For more details please visit the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html).

```
db.EvaluatedSentiments.aggregate([
{
    $group:{_id:null,avgbvc: {$avg:"$bvc"}}
}
]).forEach(printjson)
```

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? This will be very useful for understanding. Thank you!