# Calculate the average value of a mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, average

Suppose that I have a collection like this:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  city: "New York",
  state: "NY",
  murders: 328
}

{
  _id: 2,
  city: "Los Angeles",
  state: "CA",
  murders: 328
}

...
```

The collection shows us the number of murders in all cities of USA. I'd like to calculate the average of murders in all the country. I tried to use

```
$group:

db.murders.aggregate([{$group: {_id:"$state", pop: {$avg:"$murders"} } }])
```

But I get as result the murders by state:

```
{ "_id" : "NY", "murders" : 200 }

{ "_id" : "NJ", "murders" : 150 }

{ "_id" : "CA", "murders" : 230 }

{ "_id" : "CT", "murders" : 120 }
```

My question is, how can I group this result to calculate an unique average? Something like this:

```
{ "_id" : "USA", "murders" : 175 }
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try grouping by null.

```
db.murders.aggregate([{$group: {_id:null, pop: {$avg:"$murders"} } }])
```

[More-Info: mongo-average-aggregation-query-with-no-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323515/mongo-average-aggregation-query-with-no-group)