# add more than one field using $addFields

Tags: mongodb

With this code I am trying to list data from my database, and especially 2 fields especially `like` and`dislike`. The problem is that I don't know how to put both, I can only put one at a time or else I will get an error.

```
   Noticia.aggregate([
        {
            $addFields: {
                like: {
                    $cond: [{ $in: ["5e7ffb641650a326dcc1e1c7", "$likes"] }, true, false]
                }
          //I am getting error if I put this field too
                /*,
                dislike: {
                    $cond: [{ $in: ["5e7ffb641650a326dcc1e1c7", "$dislikes"] }, true, false]
                }
                */
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: {
                _id: -1 
            }
        },
        {
            $skip: desde
        },
        {

            $limit: limite
        },

    ], (err, noticia) => {

        // console.log(trans);
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                ok: false,
                err
            });
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
            ok: true,
            data: noticia
        });

    })
```

Comment: what is your error? Can you provide sample data?

Comment: It seems to be ok unless `dislikes` is not an array, anyway give us error with help..

Comment: @whoami guys excuse me. I'm not sure, but this worked. I will delete the question, I think what happened was that I created a record by mistake and that's why I was getting an error since the new record did not have the correct structure. I have this question in case you can help me  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60961072/what-is-the-equivalent-of-findone-using-aggregate-in-mongodb