# What is the equivalent of findOne using .aggregate in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Basically with this I manage to return all my objects from a collection. How can I return a single element, for example
   in the style of `findOne({_ id:" 5e82d378527bb420a4001aaf ")`?

I know how to use $match, but this returns various results.

```
let _id="5e82d378527bb420a4001aaf"

Noticia.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            like: {
                $cond: [{ $in: [_id, "$likes"] }, true, false]
            },
            dislike: {
                $cond: [{ $in: [_id, "$dislikes"] }, true, false]
            }

        }
    }

], (err, noticia) => {

    // console.log(trans);
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            ok: false,
            err
        });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({
        ok: true,
        data: noticia
    });

})
```

Comment: `.findOne` returns `null` or `object`, while `.aggregate` returns list

Comment: @Valijon   I just need to search for a record with a unique value. i don't know if i can use match in this case or if there is a better findOne () style path

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider a sample `names` collection:

```
{ _id: 1, name: "Jack", favoriteColor: "blue" },
{ _id: 2, name: "James", favoriteColor: "red" },
{ _id: 3, name: "John", favoriteColor: "blue" }
```

and run the following three queries using `findOne`:

```
db.names.findOne( { _id: 1 } )
db.names.findOne()
db.names.findOne( { favoriteColor : "blue" } )
```

the result is same for the three queries:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Jack", "favoriteColor" : "blue" }
```

The equivalent queries respectively using **aggregation** are the following, with the same result:

```
db.names.aggregate( [
  { $match: { _id: 1 } },
] )

db.names.aggregate( [
  { $limit: 1 }
] )


db.names.aggregate( [
  { $match: { "favoriteColor" : "blue" } },
  { $limit: 1 }
] )
```

[db.collection.findOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/index.html#definition) definition says -

> Returns one document that satisfies the specified query criteria on
>   the collection or view. If multiple documents satisfy the query, this
>   method returns the first document according to the natural order which
>   reflects the order of documents on the disk.

With `findOne` if no document is found it returns a `null`. But an [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/index.html#definition) returns a cursor, and you can apply the [cursor methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/index.html) on the result.

Comment: It returns array, how we can get only first document w/o in an array?

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil If your code is returning an _array_, use the array element access code; e.g., `myarray[0]` gets the first element of the array. If your code is returning a _cursor_ then use the cursor methods (there is a link in the above answer).

Comment: It returns the array but I want to get the first doc within the aggregate instead of returning the `myarray` and doing `myarray[0]`. Because I want to avoid using `asyc` `await` in my service function.

Comment: Aggregation query returns a cursor in case of native shell query. In case of some APIs the query can return an array. You can use `$limit: 1` aggregation stage to return one document only - but it will be in a cursor or an array (as per the software you are using). You can create a single call, for example, `db.names.aggregate( [ ... ] ).toArray()[0]` in case of a cursor - note that if the aggregation query returns no data this will throw an error.

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil (continued from previous comment) I suggest you create a new question explaining with code samples you are working on, software you are using, and other details for a proper answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/index.html) to limit no.of docs to be returned from aggregation pipeline :

```
Noticia.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            like: {
                $cond: [{ $in: [_id, "$likes"] }, true, false]
            },
            dislike: {
                $cond: [{ $in: [_id, "$dislikes"] }, true, false]
            }

        }
    } , {$limit :1} // will return first doc from aggregation result of '$addFields' stage

], (err, noticia) => {

    // console.log(trans);
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            ok: false,
            err
        });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({
        ok: true,
        data: noticia
    });
 })
```

Or if you wanted to return random single doc try [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/index.html).

Comment: Thank you, your responses are as good as ever. But I think I have not made myself understood. I just need to search for a record with a unique value. i don't know if i can use match in this case or if there is a better findOne () style way

Comment: @yavg : So you just wanted to return one doc from aggregation or multiple docs ? If you wanted to return multiple docs then what do you wanted to do with matched doc from `$match`?

Comment: @yavg : Then all you can do is `$match`

Comment: can you help me please with this hard question for me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61000005/how-to-create-an-array-on-the-output-of-a-response-using-aggregate-in-mongodb

Comment: You always shake my hand when I need you the most. Can you help me please?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61004259/add-an-element-to-an-array-if-it-exists-dont-add-it-if-it-exists-update-it

Answer (score 1):

```
//Express and mongoose
exports.getData = (req, res) => {

    Noticia.aggregate([
        {
            $addFields: {
                like: {
                    $cond: [{ $in: [_id, "$likes"] }, true, false]
                },
                dislike: {
                    $cond: [{ $in: [_id, "$dislikes"] }, true, false]
                }
    
            }
        }  
    ]
    ).then( data=>{
        res.send(data[0]); //return one document in format { ..... }
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({ 
          message: err.message 
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: This code uses the express and mongoose framework and returns a single document, without using brackets. Show the document in braces