# how to create an array on the output of a response using aggregate in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have in my collection a list of objects with this structure:

```
[
 {
    "country": "colombia",
    "city":"medellin",
    "calification": [
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "stars": 5
        },
        {
            "_id": 2,
            "stars": 3
        }
    ]
},
{
    "country": "colombia",
    "city":"manizales",
    "calification": [
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "stars": 5
        },
        {
            "_id": 2,
            "stars": 5
        }
    ]
},

{
    "country": "argentina",
    "city":"buenos aires",
    "calification": [
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "stars": 5
        },
    ]
},
{
    "country": "perú",
    "city":"cusco",
    "calification": [
        {
            "_id": 3,
            "stars": 3
        },
    ]
  }
]
```

I am trying to make a filter so that the output is an amount of arrays for each country. this is the example of the output i want.

`avg` would be result `sum` 'stars'/ `calification.length`

```
{
  "colombia": [
    {
      "city": "medellin",
      "avg": 4,
      "calification": [
        {
          "_id": 1,
          "stars": 5
        },
        {
          "_id": 2,
          "stars": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "city": "manizales",
      "avg": 5,
      "calification": [
        {
          "_id": 1,
          "stars": 5
        },
        {
          "_id": 2,
          "stars": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "argentina": {
    "city": "buenos aires",
    "avg": 5,
    "calification": [
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "stars": 5
      }
    ]
  },
  "peru": {
    "city": "cusco",
    "avg": 4,
    "calification": [
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "stars": 4
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to do this:

```
    Alcalde.aggregate([

        {
            $addFields: {
                colombia: {
                    "$push": {

                        "$cond": [{ $eq: ["$country", "'Colombia'"] }, true, null]


                    }


                }

            }
        },
        {
            $project: { colombia: "$colombia" }
        }
    ]
```

how can i do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make it more elegant.

MongoDB has [$avg](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) operator, let's use it. Also, we can use `$group` operator to group cities for the same `country`.

At the end, applying [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) + [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html)** we transform into desired result.

** it's because we cannot use such expression: `{"$country":"$city"}`

```
$replaceRoot                                 $arrayToObject

data : {              {                  [                             {
  "key" : "val",  -->   "key" : "val",     {k:"key", v: "val"},  -->     "key" : "val",
  "key2" : "val2"       "key2" : "val2"    {k:"key2", v: "val2"}         "key2" : "val2"
}                     }                  ]                             }
```

---

Try this one:

```
Alcalde.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$country",
      city: {
        $push: {
          "city": "$city",
          "avg": { $avg: "$calification.stars"},
          "calification": "$calification"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: [ [{ "k": "$_id", "v": "$city"}] ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OND_UfodIW0)

EDIT: Generic way to populate `city` inner object

`$$ROOT` is variable which stores root document
`$mergeObjects` adds / override fields to final object

```
Alcalde.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$country",
      city: {
        $push: {
          $mergeObjects: [
            "$$ROOT",
            {
              "avg": { "$avg": "$calification.stars" }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "city.country": 0
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: [
          [ { "k": "$_id", "v": "$city" } ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M3qRLsEQNu7)

Comment: Thanks a lot! How I would like to be at your level. I have one last question, you manually include `" city ":" $city ","calification": "$calification" `,  is there a way to import the rest of the collection fields without declaring them manually? (in my real example I have many other fields)

Comment: @yavg Check it again, I've added generic way. Practice, practice and practice :-)

Comment: I am quite grateful and it gives me some shame with you. I have had a question. Is it possible to filter ONLY in the case of Colombia that returns only what refers to the city of Medellin?

Comment: @yavg Sure. Check [it](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yA-ltUCg6ws)

Comment: Thank you very much, but it doesn't work. It shows the other city in Colombia that is "Manizales". And it stops showing the rest of the countries and their cities. What I want is that in the case of Colombia, it only shows the city of "Medellin"

Comment: @yavg here you [go](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1_Yle42aGD9)

Comment: I followed your logic and I am in trouble. I am relying on your answer, do you know how I can solve my problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61038004/how-to-return-current-item-in-a-search-using-in

Comment: can you help me with this please?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62394778/how-can-i-find-an-array-of-values-in-a-match-aggregation-and-group-the-result