# MongoDB - How to return matched item in an array while using $in in $group?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using MongoDB's aggregation.

Using `$in` I'm checking if a value exists in an array or not, And I want to return the matched object from `calificacion` array into `calificacion_usuario` field. (my `_id` is unique in the array).

I tried using `$first"` to return the current element. It's not working, not sure why & what to use.

How can I do it?

**Sample Doc :**

```
{
 "cargo" : "Presidente",
 "calificacion" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "5e894ae6fa9fd23780bcf472",
        "estrellas" : 3
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "5e895187fa9fd23780bcf478",
        "estrellas" : 5
    }
]}
```

**Query :**

```
    Politico.aggregate([
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$cargo",
                nuevo_formato: {
                    $push: {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                            "$$ROOT",
                            {
                                "calificacion_promedio": { $avg: "$calificacion.estrellas" },
                                "calificacion_usuario": { $cond: [{ $in: [req.body.id_usuario, "$calificacion._id"] }, "$first", false] },
                                "calificacion_numero_encuestas": { $size: "$calificacion" }

                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$first` doesn't work that way, You need to replace `$first` with below code :

```
{
  $arrayElemAt: [ /** Get an element from 'calificacion' based on position */
    "$calificacion",
    {
      $indexOfArray: ["$calificacion._id", req.body.id_usuario], /** Check in which position 'req.body.id_usuario' exists (will be a number) */
    },
  ],
}
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qnkVeu7Nguo)

**Ref :** [$indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/index.html), [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html)