# Add an element to an array, if it exists don't add it, if it exists update it

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am making a voting system in which an object will have an array called `scores`, every time it is qualified a record will be entered to this array as long as the same id does not exist.

**Sample Doc :**

```
{
 name:"jose luis",
 scores:[]
}
```

**The user push :**

```
{id:1,stars:5}
```

**Updated Doc :**

```
{
 name:"jose luis",
 scores:[{id:1,stars:5}]
}
```

**The user push 2nd time :**

```
{id:1,stars:4}
```

**Updated Doc :**

```
{
 name:"jose luis",
 scores:[{id:1,stars:4}]
}  //this should update the value of the stars under the array element with the existing id.
```

**I have tried this :**

```
   Politico.update(
        { name: "jose luis" },
        {
            $setOnInsert: { "$scores.id": body.req.id},
            "$addToSet": {
                scores: {
                    "id": body.req.id,
                    "starts": body.req.stars
                }
            }


        },
        { upsert: true }
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work, how can I fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you using MongoDB version 4.2 or above ?

Comment: 4.2.3 is my current version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MongoDB `4.2` or above as you can use [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#update-with-aggregation-pipeline) in updates, try below query :

```
Politico.updateOne(
  { name: "jose luis" },
  [{
    $addFields: {
      scores: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$scores",
          initialValue: [{ id: 1, stars: 5 }], // Input
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $in: ["$$this.id", "$$value.id"] }, /** Check id exists in 'scores' array */
              "$$value", /** If YES, return input */
              { $concatArrays: ["$$value", ["$$this"]] }/** If NO, concat value(holding array) with current object as array */
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }]);
```

You might not need `{ upsert: true }` as you're not writing a new document with `name : "jose Luis"` & respective `scores` array. But if you wanted to do that :

```
Politico.updateOne(
  { name: "jose luis" },
  [{
    $addFields: {
      scores: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$scores",
          initialValue: [{ id: 1, stars: 5 }], // Input
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $in: ["$$this.id", "$$value.id"] }, /** Check id exists in 'scores' array */
              "$$value", /** If YES, return input */
              { $concatArrays: ["$$value", ["$$this"]] }/** If NO, concat value(holding array) with current object as array */
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$addFields : {scores : { $ifNull: [ "$scores", {id : 13, stars: 3} ] }}} /** This additional 'addFields' will add 'scores' array with input object to newly created doc */
],{upsert : true});
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wQXHqpcalRf)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help, something strange happens. If I add another item with a different id from the one already found, it doesn't add it, it only updates it. If I enter an element with an id that is not present in the array, I should add it, otherwise update it. I thought the solution would be simpler XD

Comment: @yavg : Can elaborate you issues, I couldn't understand what's happening, Please provide some examples..

Comment: @yavg : That playground only for finds/aggregation, You need to test it in DB with `update()` !! It should work as expected..

Comment: excuse my ignorance, there are things that are not clear to me. for example, when you use the $ symbol twice, and what is the $reduce for in this case? you are the best!

Comment: @yavg : Can you check this :: (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html), it has most of the info that you need, let me know if you're stuck at a point..

Comment: @yavg : Also here `{scores : { $ifNull: [ "$scores", {id : 13, stars: 3} ] }}}` it should be `{scores : { $ifNull: [ "$scores", [{id : 13, stars: 3}] ] }}}` I missed to put `{id : 13, stars: 3}` in an array :-)

Comment: Path "name" is not in schema, strict mode is `true`, and upsert is `true`  :(

Comment: @yavg did not get what you’re talking about, do you mean to say it was not working earlier but now it is after few code changes?

Comment: I've been trying all the time to make it work in my actual code but it doesn't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I show you a screenshot of my real code. https://i.imgur.com/O4wX6n1.jpg. I am getting this error: "MongoError: '$ set' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$ set: {<field>: ...}}" excuse my ignorance please.

Comment: @yavg : I'm not sure why you're getting 'MongoError', but when I see ur code in `initialValue` where `_id` has to be `id_usuario` & Estrella is value in input !! (So that [{}] has to be input object in an array)..

Comment: I thank you for your patience, the truth is that I do not understand you well. https://i.imgur.com/nsKIjCT.jpg  I am getting this error "$set' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$set: {<field>: ...}}"

Comment: @yavg : Is your MongoDB version `4.2` ? Also if you're using mongoose is that the latest version that supports `4.2`, Additionally just replace `$addFields` with `$set` & give it a try - this should not be an issue but just give it a try

Comment: Thank you very much, I am sorry to ask you again for help and bother you.