# Mongodb - Aggregate match equivalent of a simple find

Tags: mongodb

I am looking to replace a working find with aggregate so I can do lookups. The problem is the format of the result is slightly different.

```
  .findOne({
  _id: postId, 
  })
```

Result is in the format :

```
{
 key: "value"
}
```

Using aggregate:

```
.aggregate(
[
 {$match:{
  _id: postId,
    }
  }
]).toArray() // result is same with and without toarray
```

Result is in the format :

```
[{
 key: "value"
}]
```

There is an extra square brackets. Should unwind be used or something to remove the resulting `[]` ?
I am not looking for a javascript workaround `which is to use [0]` but prefer a mongodb solution. I just need an object within {}

Comment: Also, see this post with related info: [What is the equivalent of findOne using .aggregate in Mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60961072/what-is-the-equivalent-of-findone-using-aggregate-in-mongodb).

Answer (score 1):

[aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db-collection-aggregate) returns an array of documents.  Technically it returns a cursor that most clients will present as an array.  This is similar to the return from `find`.

`findOne` only returns a single document, so it returns it as an object rather than an array of objects or a cursor.

The value returned from aggregate will be a cursor as long as there is at least one document to return.